# pgpool connection to postgresql status: "The node is in operation. There is connection. postgres: Down"

Tags: postgresql, pgpool

i have try configure PostgreSQL with PGPool to manage loa balance and replication, but i have error like this:

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LTvpI.png)

```
The node is in operation. There is connection.  postgres: Down

from postgreSQL service is up:
root@n43sl:/var/www# service postgresql
Usage: /etc/init.d/postgresql {start|stop|restart|reload|force-reload|status} [version ..]
root@n43sl:/var/www# service postgresql status
● postgresql.service - PostgreSQL RDBMS
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/postgresql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (exited) since Wed 2018-05-09 15:42:33 WIB; 23min ago
  Process: 16192 ExecStart=/bin/true (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 16192 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Tasks: 0 (limit: 4915)
   Memory: 0B
      CPU: 0
   CGroup: /system.slice/postgresql.service
```

configure in pgpool admin like this to backend:
[Setting PGPool Admin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u4Ddt.png)

any clue how to solve this case ?

Comment: check postgres log. I would assume pgpool cant connect to localhost:5432

Comment: try to configure, now postgres its up but pgpool get down -_-, it's like switching if pgpool up then postgres down